# Targeting an iframe and showing text at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to create a menu that targets an iframe, but will also show text in a separate div once clicked.

For example:
• Click on Menu item 1.
• "https://wikipedia.org" is loaded in an iframe.
• The address of the wikipedia page shows in a separate div.

Using some of the code I've found here, I've been able to make the menu to show the text how I want it, but I can't target an iframe at the same time.

Maybe it'd be better to use query?

Any help would be amazing!

(The Javascript function turns the clicked link to red).

```js
var Lst;

function changecolor(obj) {
    if (Lst) Lst.style.color = "#663399";
    obj.style.color = "red";
    Lst = obj;
}
```

```css
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.menu {
  font-size: 13px;
  width: 260px;
  height: 350px;
  left: 8px;
}
#tabs p {
  display: none;
  font-size: 13px;
}
#tabs p.tab1:target {
  display: block;
}
#tabs p.tab2:target {
  display: block;
}
#tabs p.tab3:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div id="tabs" class="menu">

    <a href="#tab1" class="nav-tab tab1" onclick="changecolor(this)">
 Menu item 1<br><br></a>

    <a href="#tab2" class="nav-tab nav-tab-active tab2" onclick="changecolor(this)">
 Menu item 2<br><br></a>

    <a href="#tab3" class="nav-tab nav-tab-active tab3" onclick="changecolor(this)">
 Menu item 3<br><br></a>

    <p id='tab1' class='tab1'>
      <a href="https://www.wikipedia.org">"https://www.wikipedia.org"</a>
    </p>

    <p id='tab2' class='tab2'>
      <a href="http://dictionary.reference.com">"http://dictionary.reference.com"</a>
    </p>

    <p id='tab3' class='tab3'>
      <a href="http://www.thesaurus.com">"http://www.thesaurus.com"</a>
    </p>

  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it using *JQuery*:

```
$("a").click(function(){
   $("iframe").attr("src", $($(this).attr("href")).find("a").attr("href"));
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d3k7c0rg/)

(Note that the two other links u added besides wikipedia are not loaded on their own, they they are not loading in the iframe either. U may wanna try using other links :) )

Comment: Wow this works perfectly. Not sure why the two sites don't load on JSFiddle, but they seem to load when I run it in a browser on it's own.